# Adding a title attribute to a jsf panelGroup?

Tags: html, css, jsf, mojarra

Is it possible to trick JSF to generate a title attribute for the `<div>`, when a
`<h:panelGroup>` component with `layout="block"` is used?

The `<h:panelGroup>` is used in a composite component and I can't use the `<div>` tag directly as I need the rendered attribute.

Comment: what version of jsf are you using? how about using the `div` with `title` and wrapping it with `panelGroup rendered...` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using JSF 2.2 you can make use of the *Pass-through attributes* feature, like this

```
<h:panelGroup p:title="My title"
```

Another solution could be using the `div` with `title` and wrapping it with

```
<panelGroup rendered=""
    <div title="My title"
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestions! unfortunately i can't upgrade to JSF 2.2 - but of course, wrapping the panelGroup in a div is a valid solution!

sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees ;)